# Is it possible to make a mesh in webgl using squares or boxes instead of triangles?

Tags: javascript, web, graphics, rendering, webgl

I want to know if I can make a mesh using other shapes instead of triangles in webgl… I am new to Pure Webgl even though I have been Using BabylonJS for some time now, I wanna learn more about the base code itself, maybe to make a game engine of mine one day. Thanks for replying

Comment: GPUs only render points, lines and triangles, every other shape can and has to be constructed or approximated(=>round shapes) via triangles.

Comment: Is making a 4d space possible then?

Comment: this is a really vague question, generally speaking you can have as many dimensions as you like but you'll have to project it to something that can be displayed on a screen...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.